# How to change string to lower case?

Tags: java, lowercase

Trying to make it so that if the user enters any vowel capitalized, it will return true. So, that's where I added the "letter = letter.toLowerCase();" but it's not working still..

```
    public static boolean isVowel (String letter) {
        letter = letter.toLowerCase();
        if (letter == "a" || letter == "e" || letter == "i" || letter == "o" || letter == "u" ) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for why you never use `==` with strings. Instead, use `.equals("a")` etc.

Comment: If you were to use any decent IDE, it will warn you about doing String comparison using `==`. You will save yourself a lot of time and energy in the long run. I suggest you stop using whatever you're currently using. Install IntelliJ. If you have any aspiration to be a professional programmer, you will likely end up using it. May as well start now.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse at the moment. Is that bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `if (letter.equals("a") ||` and so on.

`==` tests the memory references of `String` variables, not the contents of the references.

The `equals` method of the `String` class tests the contents of the references.

Comment: Perhaps using the `equalsIgnoreCase()` method would be better in this case?

Comment: Perhaps. It is up to the op.

Comment: @hooknc How would I use the equalsIgnoreCase()?

Comment: Also, you can avoid chain of conditional statement in your code using something like this :
       
public class Test {
 
 private static final String vowelStr = "aeiou";
 
 public static void main(String [] args) {
  boolean isVowel = isVowel("a");
  System.out.print(isVowel);
 }
 
 public static boolean isVowel (String letter) {
  return vowelStr.contains(letter) ? true : false;
       }

 }